# Postgres moving average

Tags: sql, postgresql

Attempting to verify my moving average calculation ... BUT I get two different values, I'd expect each query to return the same value :

```
select sum(a.processing) / 50 as myMean
from (select created, processing
      from myTable
      where name = 'stack'
      order by created desc
      limit 50) a
union
select b.*
from (select AVG(processing) 
      filter (where name = 'stack') 
      OVER (ORDER BY created desc ROWS BETWEEN 49 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
      from myTable
      where name = 'stack'
      order by created desc
      limit 1) b
```

The first query I get sum up the processing values, and divide by N (50 here), the second query I try to use a window function to achieve the same thing - which is obtaining the mean processing value for the last 50 rows where name = stack.

Comment: What is the problem? this seem totally match what you describe? It will be easier to understand what you want with some sample data and expect output.

Comment: @T.Peter I get two different values, I would expect the values to be the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ROWS BETWEEN 50 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` clause would process 51 rows (50 preceding plus the current row).

The first query without window function would process 50 rows.

Also, your `OVER` clause should be `FOLLOWING`, not `PRECEDING`:

```
OVER (ORDER BY created desc ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 49 FOLLOWING ROW)
```

The way it is written now, it shows the average of just the first row, i.e. the value of the first row, not the average of the first 50 rows.

Comment: Changed to forty nine, still get different results for each query, will update question

Comment: @NimChimpsky, the `OVER` clause should have the `FOLLOWING`, not `PRECEDING` frame. Sample data and expected results in the question usually help significantly to get good correct answers.

Comment: @NimChimpsky, you can play with simple example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6de0a405e84a0dd11e24e22344e0cf85). Try different variants and you'll see yourself how it works. This is why it is useful to have some sample data - you can quickly check that the query produces expected results.

Answer (score 2):

I think the part where OP misunderstand is the `order by` in windows function `over` :

```
select b.*
from (select AVG(processing) 
      filter (where name = 'stack') --filter do nothing here 
      OVER (ORDER BY created desc ROWS BETWEEN 50 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
      from myTable
      where name = 'stack' --where clause already filter the name
      order by created desc
      limit 1) b
```

let's modify this a bit to show what `order by` actually do in this query.

```
select b.*
from (select AVG(processing) 
      OVER (ORDER BY created desc ROWS BETWEEN 50 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
      from myTable
      where name = 'stack'
      order by created desc
      ) b --remove limit
```

with pseudo [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c7eea644aa00d49e7c8860a674d30ff7)

### pseudo table:

```
| processing | created | name |
|------------|---------|------|
|          6 |       6 | a    |
|          5 |       5 | a    |
|          4 |       4 | a    |
|          3 |       3 | a    |
|          2 |       2 | a    |
|          1 |       1 | a    |
```

### output:

```
| avg | path      |
|-----|-----------|
|   6 |6          |
| 5.5 |6+5        |
|   5 |6+5+4      |
| 4.5 |6+5+4+3    |
|   4 |6+5+4+3+2  |
| 3.5 |6+5+4+3+2+1|
```

as you see without `limit` order will try to average the current row and preceding rows(in this case 50 preceding rows).
but when you add `limit 1` in the query, it will only return the first row from output, therefor OP only see the first row as output which make OP confuse about the different result.

***TL;DR :***

the second part of the query basically return the first row result (after order) , which is meaningless since one entry average by one is... meaningless.

here is [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/avg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for better examine.

---

BTW, `Sum(col) / n` is a dangerous way to get average, if the column data is store as integer you will get a really inaccurate result, for example if the true average is `3.5` you will get `3` instead. If getting average is your goal you should aways use proper function `avg()`.

Comment: This is incorrect, you've also linked to msdn when I specified postgres

Comment: link to msdn is a oops but postgres aggregate function with windows function is identical. they are basically the same thing.

Comment: and what do you mean incorrect, your query do the thing which I answer, you use `over` completely wrong which I try to point this out.

Comment: The limit doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: the limit do what I think it does, the only thing this do is specify how many row to process... `limit 1` =  first row, `limit 2`=  first and second rows...

Comment: Yeah but not in the window function

Comment: Do you even know there is no limit clause in window function? Or do you really understand window function? and limit is always apply after the window function. in window function we use FRAME.

Comment: also @VladimirBaranov solution is absolutely correct, the reason why you get different result, I guess, is your datatype. which i Include in last part of my answer.